# Заполнение списка из бинарного файла и вывод данных

Tags: списки, pascal

Вот здесь список вроде бы генерируется, но вывести его не могу. Может, вывод куда-то перенаправлен? Помогите найти ошибку. На консоль ничего не выводится.

```
program main;
const a: array[1..8] of Integer = (153, 967, 8, 0, 9, 22, 35, 1);
type List=^node;
     node=record
        data: Integer;
        next: list
        end;
var lst: List;

procedure InputSeq(head: List);
var input: File;
    p, q: List;
begin
    AssignFile(input, 'sequence.dat');
    reset(input);
    while not eof(input) do begin
        new(p);
        read(input, p^.data);
        if head=nil then
            head:=p
        else q^.next:=p;
        q:=p;
    end;
    p^.next:=nil;
    CloseFile(input);
end;

procedure CreateBinFile();
var f:file of Integer;
    i: Integer;
begin
    assign (f,'sequence.dat');
    rewrite (f);
    i:=1;
    while i<=8 do begin
        write (f,a[i]);
        i:=i+1;
    end;
    close (f);
end;

procedure OutputSeq(head: List);
var p: List;
begin
    p:=head;
    while p<>nil do begin
        write(p^.data, ' ');
        p:=p^.next;
    end;
end;

procedure InsertDownSort(head: List);
begin
    {...}
end;

begin
    if not (FileExists('sequence.dat')) then
        CreateBinFile();
    InputSeq(lst);
    OutputSeq(lst);
end.
```

Comment: И что, на консоль не выводятся даже сообщения об ошибках компиляции?

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее писать так:
    procedure InputSeq(var head: List);

Иначе локальные изменения параметра head не изменят глобального значения переменной lst.